# get the values mit highets value sql

Tags: sql, oracle, function, window, max

the following table is given (in Oracle);

```html
LVL KID     FATHER
1   POD001 DPR001
1   POD002 DPR002
1   POD003 POD002
2   POD003 DPR002
2   POD004 DPR001
1   POD004 POD001
2   POD005 POD002
1   POD005 POD003
3   POD005 DPR002
```

I want to get for all kids the father. If the there are more than one father (POD003, POD004 and POD005), take the value with the highest value from LVL column.

Result must be like this;

```html
   LVL   KID       FATHER
    1   POD001 DPR001
    1   POD002 DPR002
    2   POD003 DPR002
    2   POD004 DPR001
    3   POD005 DPR002
```

Thank you for your help.

Regards
Serdar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You group by kid and get the maximum level and join to the main table:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join (
  select kid, max(lvl) maxlvl 
  from tablename
  group by kid
) g
on g.kid = t.kid and g.maxlvl = t.lvl
order by t.kid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bb8662ebd57a70c86a1c16657a507b37)

or with NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where kid = t.kid and lvl > t.lvl
)
order by t.kid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a28a0677a5f6dfc211acbfd06eca9535)

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation in Oracle:

```
select max(lvl) as lvl, kid,
       max(father) keep (dense_rank first order by lvl desc) as father
from t
group by kid;
```

The `keep` keyword is used (in this case) to implement an aggregate "first value" functionality.  In practice, I find that it works very efficiently.

Of course, you can compare it to other methods, such as:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.lvl = (select max(t2.lvl) from t t2 where t2.kid = t.kid);
```

Comment: I liked the version with **keep** also. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` windows function

```
with cte as
(
 select *,row_number()over(partition by kid order by lvl desc) rn
 from table_table
) select * from cte where cte.rn=1
```